# Google Sheets, the functions does not work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The following functions does not work in my Google Sheets table:

```
=IF(AND(K5="yes";L5<=10000);L5*R4;IF(AND(K5="yes";L5>10000);L5*S4,"hello"))
```

Please help me, I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(K5="yes"; L5<=10000); L5*R4;
 IF(AND(K5="yes"; L5>10000);  L5*S4; "hello"))
```